# How do I use ggplot2 to manually assign hexadecimal colors to each data point in a plot or bar graph?

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2

I have a data set, and one of the variables is a factored array with hexadecimal characters (e.g. '#00FF00').  One of the things I wanted to try doing is creating a bar plot with all of the different colors combined.

I tried using

`cg<-ggplot(my.data,aes(x=factor(1),fill=as.character(my.color)))`

followed by

`cg+geom_bar()`

but the only colors plotted seem to be ones from the default scale.  I've tried omitting the as.character() part of the code, but it doesn't make a difference. I also have the same issue when making 2d plots with geom_point().

If I try something like

`plot(my.data$var1,my.data$var2,col=as.character(my.color))`

the colors are plotted the way I wanted them, although the graph doesn't look as nice as the ones in ggplot2.

Is there something obvious I'm missing, or is this beyond the scope of ggplot2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add `scale_fill_identity()` to use color names as actual colors.

```
ggplot(my.data,aes(x=factor(1),fill=my.color)) +
   geom_bar()+
   scale_fill_identity()
```